# Handling AJAX Errors with Redux Form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm new to React/Redux so I'm building a simple blog app with Redux Form to help me learn. Right now I'm unclear on how I would handle ajax errors when submitting data from the form to the api in my action. The main issue is that I'm using the onSubmitSuccess config property of Redux Form and it seems to always be called, even when an error occurs. I'm really unclear on what triggers onSubmitSuccess or onSubmitFail. My onSubmitFail function is never executed, but my onSubmitSuccess function always is, regardless of whether an error occurred or not.

I read about [SubmissionError](https://redux-form.com/7.1.1/docs/api/submissionerror.md/) in the redux-form docs, but it says that the purpose of it is *"to distinguish promise rejection because of validation errors from promise rejection because of AJAX I/O"*. So, it sounds like that's the opposite of what I need.

I'm using redux-promise as middleware with Redux if that makes any difference.

Here's my code. I'm intentionally throwing an error in my server api to generate the error in my createPost action:

**Container with my redux form**

```js
PostsNew = reduxForm({
  validate,
  form: 'PostsNewForm',
  onSubmit(values, dispatch, props) {
    // calling my createPost action when the form is submitted.
    // should I catch the error here?
    // if so, what would I do to stop onSubmitSuccess from executing?
    props.createPost(values)
  }
  onSubmitSuccess(result, dispatch, props) {
    // this is always called, even when an exeption occurs in createPost()
  },
  onSubmitFail(errors, dispatch) {
    // this function is never called
  }
})(PostsNew)
```

**Action called by onSubmit**

```js
export async function createPost(values) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('/api/posts', values)
    return {
      type: CREATE_POST,
      payload: response
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // what would I do here that would trigger onSubmitFail(),
    // or stop onSubmitSuccess() from executing?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, `redux-form` doesn't know whether form submission was succeeded or not, because you are not returning a Promise from `onSubmit` function.

In your case, it's possible to achieve this, without using `redux-promise` or any other async handling library:

```js
PostsNew = reduxForm({
  validate,
  form: 'PostsNewForm',
  onSubmit(values, dispatch, props) {
    // as axios returns a Promise, we are good here
    return axios.post('/api/posts', values);
  }
  onSubmitSuccess(result, dispatch, props) {
    // if request was succeeded(axios will resolve Promise), that function will be called
    // and we can dispatch success action
    dispatch({
      type: CREATE_POST,
      payload: response
    })
  },
  onSubmitFail(errors, dispatch) {
    // if request was failed(axios will reject Promise), we will reach that function
    // and could dispatch failure action
    dispatch({
      type: CREATE_POST_FAILURE,
      payload: errors
    })
  }
})(PostsNew)
```

Comment: This works great. For some reason I assumed that things like ajax calls should only be handled inside of your actions. I hadn't considered doing it inside of my onSubmit function.

Answer (score 1):

For handling asynchronous actions you should use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk), [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org) or an other middleware which makes it possible to run asynchronous code.

Comment: I'm aware that using middleware is the best approach for handling asynchronous actions. I don't know if you noticed that I said that I'm using redux-promise middleware in my question? I could use redux-thunk instead, but my problem is that I don't know what to do to handle the error when using this middleware. I don't know what would cancel the onSubmitSuccess function I have configured with redux-form, or what would trigger onSubmitFail instead. The question is about how to handle the errors with redux-form specifically.